# Styling menu block's menu links in Drupal 7

Tags: templates, drupal, hook, drupal-themes

I'm trying to style a block in Drupal 7 and I'm having a very hard time figuring things out!

I've used the menu_block module to get all links from the main menu. It produces a block with links in a ul, which I would like to theme as divs for each menu tree.

The styling itself should be easy, but I'm really struggling with finding the theme hook/template filename that I should use to style it.

I've tried to hook into `theme_menu_tree` and `theme_menu_link`, but they theme way too many places, and I can't see what I'm styling. I've tried `menu-tree--menu-block--main-menu.tpl.php`, but the variables are nothing like what I need.

My thought is that I need to style the `$content` variable in `block.tpl.php`, but I can't figure out how to do it for a specific block. Where should I hook in, if I want to style the menu points when the block (block type) is display (in the footer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest (not necessarily the best) place to do this in [`hook_block_view_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7)

```
function MYMODULE_block_view_alter(&$data, $block) {
 if ($block->module == 'menu_block') {
    // Extract the links from the available data
    $links = element_children($data['content']['#content']);
    $content = '';

    // Loop through the links and build up the required output.
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      $content .= '<div class="something">' . l($link['#title'], $link['#href']) . '</div>';
    }

    // Assign the new output to the block content...done :)
    $data['content'] = $content; 
  }
}
```

The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and it's handy `dpm()` function are your best friend here...they'll let you examine any PHP variable in a nicely structured format in the standard messages area. If you don't already have it installed I'd advise doing so, it's an absolute must for Drupal development.

Don't forget to clear Drupal's caches once you've implemented that hook or the system won't pick it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the job :) But it seems dangerous to override the content of $data['content']. What if another module does the same thing, then my code will be likely to break :S You said it was not necessarily be the best way. Have you got other ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Thinking about I'm not sure there is a better way, it just felt like there should be at the time :) You can make sure your hook is called last in the process by setting the `weight` column for your module to a high number in the `system` table...that will make sure your overridden content will alway 'win' so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem trying to figure out how to name my templates and hooks properly. Googling didn't help (way too much noise), but eventually I tried the [Menu Block module documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1934824) on drupal.org and it lead me in the right direction...

Template: `menu-block-wrapper--main-menu.tpl.php`

```
<nav role="navigation" id="siteNavigation">
<?php echo render($content); ?>
</nav>
```

Hooks: `THEMENAME_menu_tree__menu_block__MENUNAME()` and `THEMENAME_menu_link__menu_block__MENUNAME()`:

```
function THEME_menu_tree__menu_block__main_menu($vars) {
    return '<ul class="my-custom-menu-wrapper">' . $vars['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

function THEME_menu_link__menu_block__main_menu($data) {

    $el = $data['element'];

    // ... render any classes or other attributes that need to go in this <li> 
    $attr = drupal_attributes($el['#attributes']);

    // ... render the menu link
    $link = l($el['#title'], $el['#href'], $el['#localized_options']);

    // ... and render any submenus
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($el['#below']);

    return sprintf("\n<li %s>%s %s</li>", $attr, $link, $sub_menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With print theme you can put CSS styles to the < ul >

```
print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links($your_menu_name), 'attributes' => array('class'=> array('ul_class')) ));
```